# How can I save every data in JSON file? android studio

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-internal-storage

I am using android studio. Code java. I save the data entered from the edittext as json by creating a file on the internal storage of the device. But it only shows the last data I entered. Each new data erases and overwrites the other.I want it to save every data I entered from the edittext in order, and to see all of them.How can I do that ?

my code:

```
 saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    String getname = editTextFileName.getText().toString();
                    String getdata= editTextData.getText().toString();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.put("Name", getname );
                    jsonObject.put("Enroll_No", getdata );
                    jsonObject.put("Mobile", "4.example");
                    jsonObject.put("Address", "4.example");
                    jsonObject.put("Branch", "4.example");



                    String userString = jsonObject.toString();
                    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(),"user.json");
                    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                    bufferedWriter.write(userString);
                    bufferedWriter.close();



                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });
```

Comment: Try new FileWriter(file, "wa"); to append data. Or do not use FileWriter if it cannot append but just FileOutputStream.

Comment: `I want it to save every data I entered from the edittext ` You wanna append all data to the same file.

Comment: @blackapps thank you for your answer. What is the difference between "FileWriter" and "FileOutputStream" ?

Comment: A writer writes. A stream streams. You cannot compare them.

Answer (score 1):

Change `FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);`
to `FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);` for append.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter

Comment: Thank you this worked. But inside the json file it gives this error: JSON standard allows only one top-level  value:1

Comment: And do you understand that error? Have a look at your ,json file with a plain text editor. And then post your file when it appended once. And post yet another time so we see how it should look like.

Comment: well yeah.. if you want to have a valid big json, you would have to read the file first into a json object and then append your data and write it back to file (then you don't need append anymore for the file) you will probably want a json array structure in the json object you append new data to. I hope this is enough info for you to get started.